# Sequence of natural numbers with special properties

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a sequence of natural numbers such that any its subsequence has two terms which are coprime? (Maybe 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, ...?)

Comment: The sequence of primes? More interestingly, numbers of the form $2^{2^n}+1$.

Comment: (This is used explicitly in a few places to prove the infinitude of primes. See for example the beginning of **The Development of Prime Number Theory: From Euclid to Hardy and Littlewood** by Wladyslaw Narkiewicz.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Consider the sequence of primes, or $a_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$. Given any finite sequence of natural numbers with this property, it is always possible to extend the sequence by an element. Since the initial sequence was finite, only finitely many primes divide its elements. Choose any primes not on this list and multiply any of them, to any power, together to get the next element.